# How to Slice the Cheese

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I encountered a problem recently stated as below:

How many pieces of cheese we can obtain from a single thick piece by making five straight slices? (we can't move the cheese when slicing) If we want to maximize the number of pieces which is denoted by $P(n)$, is there any recurrence relation for $P(n)$, where $n$ is the number of slices?

Any hints will be highly appreciated.

Comment: The first thing is that you don't have to worry too much about the shape of the cheese. If you can divide space into k pieces with n planes, then you can cut the cheese into that many pieces just by shrinking the diagram till all the intersections fit in the cheese.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was a very old Monthly problem - see below. For an excellent introduction to the general topic see Richard Stanley's paper [An Introduction to Hyperplane Arrangements (2004)](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.118.5996) and also Renteln's lecture slides [It All Depends on How You Slice It: An Introduction to Hyperplane Arrangements, 2008](http://physics.csusb.edu/~prenteln/papers/hyperintro.pdf)
[image]

Answer (score 12):

This is a special case of the problem of counting the number of
regions $\mathbb{R}^n$ is divided into by $k$ hyperplanes *in
general position*. The answer is
$$\sum_{j=0}^n {k\choose j}.$$
This is mentioned in Richard Stanley's notes on
[hyperplane arrangements](http://www-math.mit.edu/~rstan/arrangements/arr.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Robin, but Bill gives me more insight into the problem :-).

Answer (score 4):

This is the [lazy caterer's sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_caterer%27s_sequence). As others have mentioned, arbitrary dimensional analogues are called hyperplane arrangements.